# update sIFR text after ajax update

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, sifr

I am using sIFR version 3 in my site. I am updating the text in a div with id 'points' from an ajax request. I want to update the text and apply the sIFR to that div after the text is changed.

Please suggest a solution.

here is my update code

```
new Ajax.Request('score.php', {
    onSuccess: function(response) {
       $('points').update(response.responseText);
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comments . I figured out a way to use sIFR after Ajax update.

```
new Ajax.Request('score.php', {
        onSuccess: function(response) {
           $('points').update(response.responseText);
           $('points').removeClassName('sIFR-replaced');
           applySIFR();
        }
        });
```

the applySIFR(); function apply all the sIFR replacements once again.I think removing the class 'sIFR-replaced' from the element is the key to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Step one, [replace sIFR's parseSelector with jQuery](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/parseSelector) which works for Prototype as well when you write the following instead:

```
var parseSelector = $$; // prototypes querySelectorAll implementation.
```

This gives you more selector power in sIFR, because it's default implementation is rather limited.

Read '[sIFR3 documentation](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/How+to+use)' how to use sIFR3.

You should now have all jQuery selectors available in your sIFR instance, so next is to be creative.

```
new Ajax.Request('score.php', {
    onSuccess: function(response) {
        $('points').update(response.responseText);
        sIFR.replace({src:'yourFont.swf'}, { 
            selector: '#points h1' // any selector you want.
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: He's using Prototype not jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
new Ajax.Request('score.php', {
    onSuccess: function(response) {
       $('points').update(response.responseText);
       sIFR.replace(font, {
          selector: '#points'
       });
    }
});
```

Comment: Gave your prototype comment +1 this awnser -1 for copy/pasting my awnser nearly literally.

Comment: I actually posted this without seeing your answer, the answer is similar as that is the answer to his question but certainly wasn't copied from yours.